# disable the dates before the selected date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-4

I have 5 datepickers one followed by other.If I select date1 then when I select date2 it should disable all the dates before selected date and when I select date2 ,date3 should automatically come with the same date as date2 .And when I select date4 it should disable all the dates before the selected date.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service and expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1823841). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array of dates your want to disable and set their index to -1. for example

```
var array = ["2018-03-14","2018-03-15","2018-03-16","2018-03-17","2018-03-18"]

$('#your_date_field').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
});
```